# YugabyteDB xCluster replication issues with WAL

Tags: yugabytedb

Create two new Cluster (NYC and FRA) — fresh (1 node per region)
Create a new table in each NYC and FRA
Create a bi-directional replication for the table (xCluster)
All works
Delete replication (1 and 2) both direction
Alter table (add column) in each cluster (NYC and FRA)
Create replication (1 and 2) both direction. One direction works, the opposite will fail with error unable to change the WAL retention time for table)

recreate the full cluster

Comment: I belive we resolved this on Slack IIRC. If yes, can you answer the question here?

Comment: @dhYB yes solved. Thank you 

Comment: Can you paste the fix that did it? If not, maybe delete the question since we can't even debug it now.